# This code runs without errors, but cannot add anyone to any roles

Tags: discord.js

```
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const { GoogleSpreadsheet } = require('google-spreadsheet');
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] });
const PREFIX = '!';

// Specify your credentials here
const creds = {
  client_email: 'myclient',
  private_key: 'myprivatekey',
};

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

client.on('message', async (message) => {
  if (!message.content.startsWith(PREFIX) || message.author.bot) return;

  const args = message.content.slice(PREFIX.length).trim().split(/ +/);
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

  if (command === 'assignrole') {
    if (!message.member.permissions.has('MANAGE_ROLES')) {
      console.error('Error: User does not have the ManageRole permission');
      message.reply('You do not have permission to use this command');
      return;
    }

    const sheetId = args[0];
    if (!sheetId) {
      console.error('Error: Missing spreadsheet ID in command');
      message.reply('Please provide a valid spreadsheet ID');
      return;
    }

    const doc = new GoogleSpreadsheet(sheetId);
    try {
      await doc.useServiceAccountAuth(creds);
      await doc.loadInfo(); // loads document properties and worksheets
      const sheet = doc.sheetsByIndex[0]; // assumes sheet is first in document

      const rows = await sheet.getRows();
      const role = message.mentions.roles.first();
      if (!role) {
        console.error('Error: Missing role in command');
        message.reply('Please provide a valid role');
        return;
      }

      const roleName = role.name;
      const successfulUsers = [];

      for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        const row = rows[i];
        const user = message.guild.members.cache.find(
          (member) => member.user.username === row._rawData[0]
        );
        if (user) {
          try {
            await user.roles.add(role);
            row._rawData[1] = 'OK';
            await row.save();
            successfulUsers.push(user.user.username);
          } catch (err) {
            console.error(`Error: ${err.message}`);
          }
        }
      }

      message.channel.send(
        `The role ${roleName} was added to the following users: ${successfulUsers.join(', ')}`
      );
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(`Error: ${err.message}`);
      message.reply('An error occurred while trying to access the spreadsheet');
    }
  }
});

client.login('mykey');
```

This is code was made to access a google sheet, reads column A and adds specified role to Users in column A, then adds 'OK' to column B to users who actually got the roleThis runs without errors, but cannot add anyone to any roles.

How can I change this so that it reads usernames on column A, and adds the role specified in the command?

I tried with a test code that exports whats in column A, and it seems to be reading column A.
I have checked permisions on discord side and the role I was trying to assign was under the bot role.

Comment: You are missing the `MESSAGE_CONTENT` intent flag as well.

Comment: Added the MESSAGE_CONTENT flag
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES,Intents.FLAGS.MESSAGE_CONTENT] });
Had no effect on the isssue